# Assessing Impact of Categorical Features in Classification with Multiple Models

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, binary-data

I am working on a binary classification problem with a limited dataset (50 observations), aiming to understand the influence of categorical features on the target variable. I'm exploring several models within the R `caret` package, including LDA, KNN, Naive Bayes, QDA, logistic regression, SVM, random forest, and neural network. I appreciate any insights you can share about: Are all these models suitable for handling both numerical and categorical features? Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how to effectively assess the importance and contribution of the categorical features compared to the numerical ones across different models. Thanks in advance and I hope I was sufficiently clear.

The characteristics of the dataset are as follows:

- Number of features: 113 (110 numerical, 3 categorical)
- Number of observations: 50
- Number of classes: 2